# storing data on an "anonymous" user

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm currently working on developing a Symfony2 app that will not only accept 
user registrations, but will allow visitors to go through almost the 
entire flow of the site without creating an account or logging in. Design ideas look something like this (suggestions/improvements welcome):

1. When a user logs in to their account, data will be persisted to the user/related entities as normal
2. When an anonymous user hits the site for the first time, an "anonymous user entity" is created for them as if they'd registered, but with something like `USER_<session_id>` as an identifier instead of a personalized username. Any activity they perform on the site is persisted to this anonymous user entity
3. When an anonymous user chooses to register, their anonymous user entity is upgraded to a registered user entity, preserving their data for future use
4. If an anonymous user leaves the site without registering, the anonymous user entity should be cleared after a while to prevent buildup of dead data

What's the best way to go about this? Specifically, what is considered "best practice" for creating/manipulating a User entity for an anonymous user without having to place code into every controller?

Answer (score 6):

I would advise against using the IP address for this, as it could cause problems for users behind a NAT.
Using a custom cookie, or the sessionId (PHPSESSID) cookie as an identifier for tracking purposes would be a better idea. Google uses this strategy for its ads business. Stand on the shoulders of giants!

Comment: Is this similar to StackOverflow's solution (as far as I understand it, you don't need to register to ask questions)?

Comment: No, StackOverflow seems to use some kind of OpenId. It allows users to have only one ID across multiple sites. Google's authentication implements OpenId. I'm not so sure about Facebook however.

Comment: I understand the functionality for registered users, but unregistered users can participate on the site as well, and their questions are tracked on a per-user basis (some profiles say "unregistered user"). I assume your solution is similar to how they do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar to this that I've had to do.  What I did was collected the anonymous users ip address (using ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])).  I then used the ip address for tracking purposes.  You can then use that when they register to append their past usage to their newly created account.

You can then just run a simple query to drop any ip address that hasn't had activity in a while (most users have dymanic ip addresses so it will change every so often anyways).

Comment: Thinking about this, there are some holes: NAT problems, like @emilecantin points out, but also problems with mobile users, who can change IPs quickly over a short time (moving through wifi hotspots, for example).

Comment: I would definitely not use this approach. There are many instances of different user sessions active on one IP address (eg people accessing your website from work computers than share on or several IP addresses among hundreds of computers).  You need to use a unique ID in a cookie.